# Firebase Cloud Function Query Not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I deployed a function with the following query:

```
admin.firestore().collection("fcm").where("devices",'array-contains', mobile).get().then((snapshots)=> {...});
```

This returns the following error from the Cloud Function Log:

```
msgTrigger: Function execution started

msgTrigger: Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

msgTrigger: Function execution took 8429 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

msgTrigger: Unhandled rejection

msgTrigger: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined at admin.firestore.collection.where.get.then (/user_code/index.js:23:65) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Anyone please?

Fighting for days with the editor here. decided to post my function code in chunks:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var msgData;
var mobile;
```

Second part:

```js
exports.msgTrigger = functions.firestore
  .document('Messages/{MessageID}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      msgData = snapshot.data();
      mobile = msgData.mobile;

      admin.firestore().collection("fcm").where("devices", 'array-contains', mobile).get().then((snapshots) => {
```

Third part:

```js
var tokens = [];
if (snapshots.empty) {
  console.log('No devices');
} else {
  for (var token of snapshot.docs) {
    tokens.push(token.data().token);
  }
  var payLoad = {
    "notification": {
      "title": "de " + msgData.name,
      "body": "Alerta de Emergência!",
      "sound": "default",
      "icon": msgData.icon
    },
    "data": {
      "remetente": +msgData.name,
      "mensagem": "Alerta de Emergência!"
    }
  }
```

Fourth part:

```js
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payLoad).then((response) => {
console.log("mensagens enviadas");
}).catch((err) => {
console.log("erro: " + err);
});
}
});

});
```

Comment: Can you share the **entire** code of your Cloud Function pls? Also which versions of Firestore and Cloud Functions are you using.

Comment: Having a hard time adding the function code through edit. Keeps saying it looks my post has mostly code, pls add som additional info. Adding additional info does not make the error go away though.

Comment: @Renaud. I divided the function in several parts in order to be able to post it here (just couldn't get it here in 1 go). I'm using Firestore ^0.8.2+1, "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0", "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore 0.8 is quite an old version, see https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.8.x/. It is only from version 0.16 that you can use the `array-contains` query operator , see https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/releases/tag/v0.16.0. So you should update to the latest version.

I've also adapted your function code by first (and very important, see below) returning the promise returned by the first asynchronous task, then re-organising your promises chaining in the if/then/else.

Does it execute correctly now??

```
   const functions = require('firebase-functions');
   const admin = require('firebase-admin');
   admin.initializeApp();  // Here changed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase-admin

   exports.msgTrigger = functions.firestore
      .document('Messages/{MessageID}')
      .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const msgData = snapshot.data();  //No need to declare this outside of the Cloud Function, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mjfI0FYP7Y
        const mobile = msgData.mobile;

        return admin.   // <- HERE return
          .firestore()
          .collection('fcm')
          .where('devices', 'array-contains', mobile)
          .get()
          .then(snapshots => {
            let tokens = [];
            if (snapshots.empty) {
              console.log('No devices');
              return null;
            } else {
              for (var token of snapshot.docs) {
                tokens.push(token.data().token);
              }
              var payLoad = {
                notification: {
                  title: 'de ' + msgData.name,
                  body: 'Alerta de Emergência!',
                  sound: 'default',
                  icon: msgData.icon
                },
                data: {
                  remetente: +msgData.name,
                  mensagem: 'Alerta de Emergência!'
                }
              };
              return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payLoad);
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('erro: ' + err);
            return null;
          });
      });
```

Why is it important to return the promises returned by asynchronous tasks? Watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the official Firebase video series (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) for the answer!!

Removing ".where('devices', 'array-contains', mobile)" gives the same error. I added msgData.name and msgData.mobile to console.log and they get printed, so the first part is fine:

```js
1: 31: 05.140 AM
msgTrigger
Function execution started
1: 31: 11.289 AM
msgTrigger
Nome: Alan
1: 31: 11.291 AM
msgTrigger
mobile: 91983372845
1: 31: 11.291 AM
msgTrigger
erro: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
1: 31: 11.297 AM
msgTrigger
Function execution took 6158 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

[image: And here is the fcm document]

Comment: Unfortunately still showing "msgTrigger erro: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined". Sorry for not having been very clear at first, I'm using the function in a Flutter app. The Firestore ^0.8.2+1 is in pubspec.yaml. "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0" and "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0" are in packages.json in the functions folder. I only recently installed the firebase cli, so I guess the latest firestore-node.js version was installed? nodejs = 6. What update should I apply?

Comment: In package-lock.json I found: "@google-cloud/firestore": {
      "version": "0.16.1",

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for what it's worth I finally found the culprit:

```js
for (var token of snapshot.docs) {
```

snapshot should be snapshots. Yes it's emabarrasing and it took nothing less than the excellent Firebase Support Team to point it out to me. Wished Android Studio could pick up this kind of silly typos in js code.

Will still mark Renaud's answer, since he helped optimize my code and gave me some usefull tips along the way.